# Mod_rewrite with additional, undeclarated parameters from Form by GET

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, get, url-rewriting

I'm using mod_rewrites on my page, it works great but i have problems with additional, undeclarated parameters sended from FORM by GET method.

Check this code:

This is my mod_rewrites rules:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Main
RewriteRule ^index.html$                                            index.php                           [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\_]+).html$                                       index.php?page=$1                   [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\_]+)-([a-z\_]+).html$                            index.php?page=$1&method=$2         [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\_]+)-([a-z\_]+).([0-9\_]+).html$                 index.php?page=$1&method=$2&id=$3   [NC,L]
```

And my links looks like this :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/projects-add.html
```

from:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?page=projects&method=add
```

When i send a form by GET method
sample link:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/projects-add.html?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

My script doesn't see additional params.
The point is, i don't want declarate params in .httacces because quantity of params is unknown. Maybe one or maybe ten. It's depends from quantity columns in table.

I will really greatfull for help.

Regards!